# Get index of element in unfiltered vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a rle object from a vector and would like to get the sum of lengths (with values == TRUE & values == FALSE) before and after the maximum of lengths (with values == TRUE)

That I can do:

```
se <- c(3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,8,9,9,9,5,4,3,4,5,4,3,2)
obj <- rle(se > 4)

obj

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:5] 8 8 3 1 3
  values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE

#Getting the maximum with values == True
with(obj, max(lengths[values]))

8
```

However now I am not sure how to proceed,.. If I would try to find the maximum 8 via match() I would first find the element with values == FALSE and I can not rely that there is not another lengths = 8 with values == FALSE right of the maximum I am trying to look for.

For the showed example the expected result would be:

```
Sum1 = 8 
Sum2 = 7
```

Thank you a lot for your help,
yasel

Comment: I am not sure I can entirely follow you here. Is `Sum1` equal to the first `8` and `Sum2` equal to `3 + 1 + 3` from your `obj` `lenghts`?

Comment: Exactly. The maximum I found with `with(obj, max(lengths[values]))` is the second element of obj. So left of it there is only another 8 which is Sum1 and right of it there are 3 + 1+ 3 which gives 7 as Sum2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea that uses `rleid` from `data.table` in order to create `TRUE/FALSE` groups, i.e.

```
i1 <- setNames(se > 4, data.table::rleid(se > 4))
i2 <- names(which.max(tapply(names(i1)[i1], names(i1)[i1], length)))
sum1 <- length(i1[names(i1) < i2])
sum2 <- length(i1[names(i1) > i2])
sum1
#[1] 8
sum2
#[1] 7
```

You can also make it a function,

```
f1 <- function(x, size) {
    i1 <- setNames(x > size, data.table::rleid(se > size))
    i2 <- names(which.max(tapply(names(i1)[i1], names(i1)[i1], length)))
    return(c(length(i1[names(i1) < i2]), length(i1[names(i1) > i2])))
}

f1(se, 4)
#[1] 8 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach:

```
with(obj, {
    i <- which(values & lengths==max(lengths))
    c(sum(lengths[seq_len(i-1)]), sum(lengths[-seq_len(i)]))
    })
```

output:

```
[1] 8 7
```